# How do I get iPad templates to appear on new file after converting to universal application?

Tags: iphone, ipad, universal

I have converted a prior iPhone app to universal application.  It runs on the iPad and iPhone simulator but when I create a new file, none of the iPad templates are appearing.  For example, I want to select the split controller.

How do I make the iPad templates appear?

Comment: Did you add new project as Universal ? Or you just made changes in your old project to make compatible to iPad ?

Comment: I converted the target using xCode's built-in converter.  That is I started with an iPhone project and am trying to convert to Universal.  I assumed the built-in conversion would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately what you are trying to do is not that simple. After converting an iPhone application to a universal application, you cannot get SplitViewController in the options while trying to add new file. If you want to add a SplitViewController then you have to do some extra work. You have to delete your MainWindow-iPad.nib file and drag and drop SplitViewController from library and have to set it up properly.

Just have a look at http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/4/24/converting-to-a-universal-app-part-iii.html

That's perhaps what you want exactly. Hope that helps!